# Validation function testing a value only if of a given character length

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I'm writing a function that will validate certain codes.

Codes are integers that should meet two criteria:

1. be of *n* length (for the sake of this example, let's say 2)
2. more complex checks (irrelevant for this simplified example, but the key aspect is that this will require many lines of code and separate assignments)

To avoid useless calculations, I only want the function to evaluate criterion 2 if the first one is met.

```r
codes <- c(16, 19, 12, 8)

is_valid <- function(code) {
    if (nchar(code) != 2) {
        return(FALSE)
    } else {
        # This part is not relevant
        val1 <- as.integer(substr(code, 1, 1))
        val2 <- as.integer(substr(code, 2, 2))
        sum <- val1 + val2
        validator <- 10 - sum %% 3
        return(validator == 0)       
    } 
}
```

Issue: this works well if I pass a single element (e.g. `is_valid(16)`, however if I try passing a vector `is_valid(codes)`, I get this error:

`Error in if (nchar(code) != 2) { : the condition has length > 1`

I understand this is because `if` is not vectorised. I tried replacing this with `ifelse()` but it doesn't really work in this circumstance because the second criteria is a multi-line bit of code.

I have a feeling there's a simple programming solution to this.

Comment: I would either re-write your function to expect a vectorised input, or else look into the base function `Vectorize()`.

Comment: Also, the other reason `ifelse()` does not suit your use case is that `ifelse()` often calculates all the possible outputs - if at least one of the input tests evaluates "TRUE" and at least one "FALSE" it will calculate both outcomes for ALL elements of the input vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the logical test `if (nchar(code) != 2)`. In R, the logical test inside an `if` statement must return a single logical TRUE or FALSE. In your case, it will return a logical *vector*:

```r
codes <- c(16, 19, 12, 8)
nchar(codes) != 2
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The `if` statement will use the first element of this vector for flow control (while also emitting a warning), so your function will process the *entire* vector `codes` via the `else` statement.

My guess is that you want a vectorized output. In this case we can use `ifelse`, or even simply check the two logical tests independently and return their results combined by a logical AND:

```r
is_valid <- function(code) {
    
    test1 <- nchar(code) == 2

    val1 <- as.integer(substr(code, 1, 1))
    val2 <- as.integer(substr(code, 2, 2))
    sum <- val1 + val2
    validator <- (10 - sum) %% 3
    test2 <- validator == 0 & !is.na(validator)
    
    return(test1 & test2)

}

is_valid(codes)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan, this works. I was also trying to avoid conducting test2 if test1 is FALSE, in order to avoid pointless calculations.

Comment: @AndreaM the problem with that approach is that you would have to iterate through the vector in R, performing a logical test on each element to decide whether to do the second calculation. This is paradoxically much slower than just using the C-level vectorization, so the method I demonstrated here will be faster for most use-cases.